# How to update a framework in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, frameworks

I'm writing an app using Nuance's `SpeechKit` framework.  I've just downloaded a newer version of the framework that contains new methods in some of the classes.  To upgrade, I deleted the framework and the re-added the new one.  When I right-click on the framework in Xcode and click "reveal in finder", it shows the new framework.  When I open up the "Headers" subfolder of the framework in Xcode, I see the new methods.

The problem is that my class seems to still be referencing the header file in the old location, as the new methods are not visible within my application.

How do I upgrade a framework properly?  Is there somewhere else in Xcode that contains a path reference to the SDK?

Comment: Did you try "Clean all"?

Comment: Yep - no effect. Even did the usual - clean, close Xcode, reboot my mac etc. No good.

Comment: Erasing **Derived Data** usually does the trick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found what cause this issue for us.

When you build a new version you must update "Current Library Version".
There is also a "Compatibility Version"

In Xcode selector your framework target and in build settings search for linking and you will se this setting there.

We created a build script to bump this version number every time we build.

Xcode caches the frameworks and uses the cache if possible. That's why you need to change this number.

Comment: Any chance that you share the build script?

Comment: After wasting a good 2 hours on this, your answer was just the thing I needed.

Answer (score 16):

You need to delete Derived Data for the project - it is an option of the project in the XCode Organizer, on the projects tab. It will remove the cached build of the framework, forcing XCode to use the new one.

1. Choose Window/Organizer from the top menu
2. Click "Projects" pseudo-tab-thing, along the top of organizer window (icon looks like an XCode project file"
3. Select the project from the list on the left
4. Click "Delete" next to "Derived Data" in the area immediately below the project info header.
5. List item

---

**EDIT**: as of XCode 12 (should work with Xcode 8 and above), you can delete derived data like this:

Go to `File > Workspace Settings` if you are in a workspace environment or `File > Project Settings` for a regular project environment.

Then click over the little grey arrow under Derived data section and select your project folder to delete it in Finder.

Comment: This sounds promising, but can you tell me exactly how to get to whatever you're referring to? When I open up the Organizer window, I don't see any option for deleting build artifacts.

Comment: Updated my answer. It's called Derived Data, sorry; I've been in Team City all day so everything is a build artifact to me :)

Comment: I'm using Xcode 3.2.5 - when I click on the Appname.xcodeproj item under the PROJECTS & SOURCES pseudo-tab, I see nothing at all in the right pane.

Comment: Oh, sorry, this is an XCode 4 feature. The equivalent under 3.x, _I think_, is to delete the 'build' directory under your project.

Comment: The only other suggestion I can think of is to make sure simulator doesn't have any old builds of your application linked with the wrong version of the framework. Filing a bug report won't even be helpful, as I've heard Apple will tell you to upgrade to XCode 4 and try again (not helpful, I know).

Comment: @MusiGenesis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1236/discussion-between-ryanr-and-musigenesis)

Comment: sorry about that, thanks for offering to keep helping (I haven't seen the chat feature before). I ended up starting with a new project and importing my code files. After adding the SpeechKit framework and a couple of other frameworks that weren't on Nuance's "here's all the other frameworks you'll need" list I was able to see the new methods. I'm still curious about what I had to do where in Xcode in order to point the project to the correct header file. I am so totally used to this sort of thing with Xcode, though.

Comment: BTW, I've often found the extended comment threads to be highly informative and entertaining. I think a great deal might be lost because of this.

Comment: I didn't realize what was going to happen when I clicked the link. Interesting feature. XCode 4 resolves most of those problems, but introduces some new ones unfortunately.

Comment: I had this problem just now (different framework though) and the only thing that ended up working in the end was to remove all instances of the old version from my disk. I don't know which version it was linking to, but it certainly wasn't the one in my source folder or referred to in the linking instructions page. Once I deleted the other ones, it compiled OK and the files are detected OK. HTH.

Comment: This solved it for me. When developing your own framework, adding it as a dependent Framework (include the xcode project) is solving a lot of headaches

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7 and instead I had to go to Window>Projects to delete derived data. But even after I did this, my project still seems to think my framework exists!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CocoaPods, run `pod update [PODNAME]`.