# Update framework inside app when framework source code is changed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

Trying this framework updation thing first time !

My app is using an external framework for which i have the source code. The app has the .framework file included inside it

What i want to achieve :

> I change the source code in the framework outside the app and build and that changes should be made when i access it from the app

What i did so far:

1. Changed a single method declaration inside the framework source code (say earlier it was returning `String` but i changed it to return `String?` now)
2. Build the framework which generated a new `.framework` file
3. Deleted the old `.framework` file from the app added the new `.framework` file
4. Build the app

Result :

> Error: No such module "Framework Name"

I am using Xcode 11 and under **Framework,Libraries and Embedded Content** , that framework exists (though it does not have the usual yellow briefcase icon but a white one)

I referred to this one : [How to update a framework in an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615494/how-to-update-a-framework-in-an-ios-app) but in this the particular error is not coming

Is there any other way to update the framework or am i missing something

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this myself.  I'm using Xcode 11:

Go to File > Swift Packages > Update to latest package versions

In my case this caused Xcode to pull the latest version from GitHub.

Hope it helps!

Also, I did update my framework, checked it in, and tagged it with a new version number.

Just re-read your question, and realized you have embedded the framework, so this probably won't work for you.  In my case a package was created for the framework.  I see that's not the case here.